# Embed BIRT Report Viewer inside the html page

Tags: html, birt

I have some BIRT Reports in different pages(it seems in xml). I am also very new in the BIRT.

Can I able to embed BIRT Reports in HTML?

Comment: You made relative statement with "some BIRT reports in different pages". I assume you want to open your reports in current window from your web application? This can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/birt.tld" prefix="birt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>My Report - JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <birt:viewer
        id="birtViewer"
        reportDesign="SD.rptdesign"
        pattern="frameset"
        height="800"
        width="775"
        isHostPage="false"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="false"
        style="border-radius:25px; border:3px solid silver"
        format="html">
        </birt:viewer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have solved by doing like this...

Comment: What if i would like to integrate birt viewer in plain HTML page where i can write only JavaScript code?