# How to embed a BIRT report in HTML?

Tags: html, birt

I'm sorry before I ask this question, because i can't put a comment on the previously asked question about the same topic so I ask it here.
I found this question :

[Embed BIRT Report Viewer inside the html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135068/embed-birt-report-viewer-inside-the-html-page)

I have searched for a way and I found a program called Actuate BIRTiHub FType. My question is, is there any other way to embed the `.rptdesign` file inside a HTML page without install BIRTiHub program?